# Tkinter: Handling multiple identical labels with different text

Tags: python, tkinter

What would be the best way to create identical labels that all display similar information? For example:

```
number_label = Label(self, text="Number:")
number_value_label = Label(self, text="")

number2_label = Label(self, text="Number:")
number2_value_label = Label(self, text="")

number3_label = Label(self, text="Number:")
number3_value_label = Label(self, text="")

number_label.pack()
number2_label.pack()
number3_label.pack()
number1_value_label.pack()
number2_value_label.pack()
number3_value_label.pack()

number_value_label.config(text="1")
number2_value_label.config(text="2")
number3_value_label.config(text="3")
```

The text will change dynamically. Is there a better way to do this?

The goal is to display the labels on the grid where the values for those labels will be to the right of the display label. In total there will be 40 labels.

Comment: Try to generate all this stuff in a loop and store it in structure (for e.g. a dict `{id: [number_label, number_value_label]}`).

Comment: The answer depends on what you're really trying to accomplish besides having "multiple labels". Should the values appear immediately below the labels? To the right of the labels? Are you creating a grid of information or something more like a form with multiple fields of different types? Are you creating just three, or potentially dozens?

Comment: Good point, I will update my question.

Comment: It seems like all you need is a simple loop. Have you tried using a loop?